# распараллеливание с omp инициализации вектора случайными числами

Tags: c++, многопоточность, случайные-числа

имеется такой участок кода, здесь состояние generator меняется из всех потоков, каким образом элегантно можно сделать, безопасное разделение генератора на все потоки? критическая секция только замедлит работу, threadprivate тоже не подходит, потому что от вызова к вызову фу-ии generateVector меняется кол-во потоков

```
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <omp.h>


std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 generator(rd());
const int A = -10;
const int B = 10;
const std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniformDistribution(A, B);

template<typename T>
void generateVector(std::vector<T>& vec)
{
  const int size = vec.size();

#pragma omp parallel for 
  for (int i = 0;i < size;++i) {
    vec[i] = uniformDistribution(generator);
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<double> values(100000);
  generateVector(values);


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: кол-во потоков можно ограничить, я бы если генераторы независимы, сделал несколько генераторов, по числу потоков

Comment: А зачем вам подобное распараллеливание? Не является ли оно преждевременной оптимизацией?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch это уже последний этап, нужно много векторов и матриц генерировать и генерация занимает половину времени от всей работы